# Images wont change HTML

Tags: javascript, html

It's been a while since I've used html and am trying to make a simple dice rolling website. However, the images don't change in the text file, after I press the designated button. I've tried everything I could think of, and have spent 5+ hours trying to figure out why it does work.

```html
<html>
<h1>Dice roller</h1>
<p>Roll a dice to recieve a reward base on your roll.</p>
<script>
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var dieroll = 0;
function roll(){
    var image = document.getElementById("dice");
    dieroll = getRandomInt(1,6);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = dieroll;
    if (dieroll==1){
        image.src="1die.jpg";
    } else {
        if (dieroll ==2){
            image.src="2die.jpg";
        }
    } else {
        if (dieroll==3){
        image.src="3die.jpg";
    }
        
    } else {
       if (dieroll==4){
        image.src="4die.jpg";
    } 
    } else {
        if (dieroll==5){
        image.src="5die.jpg";
    }    
    } else {
        if (dieroll==6){
        image.src="6die.jpg";
    } 
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<button onclick="roll()">Click me to roll</button>
</body>
<h2>The value for your roll is:  <div id="result"></div></h2>
<div>
<img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.a84-UisZ9wZzwQZdXumxTgHaHV?w=174&h=180&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7" id="dice" width="100" height="100">    
</div>
</html>
```

Additionally, the images I'm trying to use file names are entered correctly, and the original image appears just fine, just changing it is what isn't working.

Comment: Did you try by comparing with === and also why don’t you try using image.setAttribute() for updating the src ?

Comment: Also use else if () instead of nested else and if, do these changes and let me know if that doesn’t works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if else` statements had several errors, here it is fixed.

Other than that you have to make sure the images, such as 4die.jpg, are in the same directory as your html file, otherwise you need to print the full absolute or relative html, for example `/images/4die.jpg` or `images/4die.jpg`

```html
<html>
<h1>Dice roller</h1>
<p>Roll a dice to recieve a reward base on your roll.</p>
<script>
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var dieroll = 0;
function roll(){
    var image = document.getElementById("dice");
    dieroll = getRandomInt(1,6);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = dieroll;
    if (dieroll==1){
        image.src="1die.jpg";
    } else if (dieroll ==2){
        image.src="2die.jpg";
    } else if (dieroll==3){
        image.src="3die.jpg";
    } else if (dieroll==4){
        image.src="4die.jpg";
    } else if (dieroll==5){
        image.src="5die.jpg";
    } else if (dieroll==6){
        image.src="6die.jpg";
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<button onclick="roll()">Click me to roll</button>
</body>
<h2>The value for your roll is:  <div id="result"></div></h2>
<div>
<img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.a84-UisZ9wZzwQZdXumxTgHaHV?w=174&h=180&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7" id="dice" width="100" height="100">    
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Although the switch approach in Pranav Rustagi's answer is indeed a better option than using several if else

Comment: If you found it useful please mark the checkmark and/or upvote on the left, thank you

Comment: Don't have enough rep unfortunately. Hopefully people these comments and upvote themselves. I'll accept it when it allows (takes 2 minutes)

Comment: It is your question so it's up to you to select the correct answer, even you have no rep. Doesn't have to be my answer though, as I said I would go with the switch approach

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it did not work was because your nested if-else statements were too messed up. Here is a better approach using `switch` case.

You can inspect to see change in `src`:

**Working snippet :**

```html
<html>
<h1>Dice roller</h1>
<p>Roll a dice to recieve a reward base on your roll.</p>
<script>
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  var dieroll = 0;

  function roll() {
    var image = document.getElementById("dice");
    dieroll = getRandomInt(1, 6);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = dieroll;

    switch (dieroll) {
      case 1:
        image.src = "1die.jpg";
        break;
      case 2:
        image.src = "2die.jpg";
        break;
      case 3:
        image.src = "3die.jpg";
        break;
      case 4:
        image.src = "4die.jpg";
        break;
      case 5:
        image.src = "5die.jpg";
        break;
      case 6:
        image.src = "6die.jpg";

    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <button onclick="roll()">Click me to roll</button>
</body>
<h2>The value for your roll is:
  <div id="result"></div>
</h2>
<div>
  <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.a84-UisZ9wZzwQZdXumxTgHaHV?w=174&h=180&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7" id="dice" width="100" height="100">
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 else statements after your initial if statement. You're gonna want to change them to either "**if**" or "**else if**" statements and that should do the trick.

FROM:

```
if(dieroll==1)image.src="1die.jpg";} else {if (dieroll ==2){image.src="2die.jpg";}
```

TO:

```
if(dieroll==1){image.src="1die.jpg";}else if (dieroll
==2){image.src="2die.jpg";}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should have been a very, very long time since you last worked with HTML/javascript. Your code is well written programatically, but doesn't work due to several syntax errors.

To start with, you have some elements outside of the `<body>` elements. Moving to the javascript, you cannot have an else statement, unless it is preceded by either an `if` or `else if` statement. Instead of

```
if (condition1) {
  // do something
} else {
  if(condition2) {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

you need to use

```
if (condition1) {
  // do something
} else if(condition2) {
  // do something else
}
```

After applying these fixes, your code works as it should:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var dieroll = 0;

function roll() {
  var image = document.getElementById("dice");
  dieroll = getRandomInt(1, 6);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = dieroll;
  if (dieroll == 1) {
    image.src = "1die.jpg";
  } else if (dieroll == 2) {
    image.src = "2die.jpg";
  } else if (dieroll == 3) {
    image.src = "3die.jpg";
  } else if (dieroll == 4) {
    image.src = "4die.jpg";
  } else if (dieroll == 5) {
    image.src = "5die.jpg";
  } else if (dieroll == 6) {
    image.src = "6die.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="roll()">Click me to roll</button>
<h2>The value for your roll is:
  <div id="result"></div>
</h2>
<div>
  <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.a84-UisZ9wZzwQZdXumxTgHaHV?w=174&h=180&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7" id="dice" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```